# Unable to read MySQL log file

Tags: java, string, logging

Hey I am trying to read any "root" string in the log file name "SHIKHAR.log" but the compiler keeps on showing.

```
dam.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
       System.out.println("I found in file " +SHIKHAR.getName());
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable SHIKHAR
  location: class dam
1 error
```

I am not sure what's wrong with it I have tried appending the extensions and try it otherwise aswell but it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class dam 
{
public static void main (String arg[])
{
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner("SHIKHAR");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
   if(lineFromFile.contains("root")) { 
       // a match!
       System.out.println("I found in file " +SHIKHAR.getName());
       break;
   }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you define SHIKHAR?

Comment: final Scanner scanner = new Scanner("SHIKHAR");

Comment: in this line i have defined

Comment: So you assume ``new Scanner("SHIKHAR");`` and ``SHIKHAR.getName()`` with an undefined ``SHIKHAR`` magically interacts with your log file? Why?

Comment: @ShikharGupta no, in that line you defined a ``Scanner`` instance with a reference named ``scanner``.

Comment: No you didn't. You defined `scanner` and passed the string "SHIKHAR" to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are using undefined variable name **SHIKHAR**.

```
System.out.println("I found in file " +SHIKHAR.getName());
```

As per your assumption `SHIKHAR` is file but here in your code its just a string literal.

You can define a variable as

```
final File SHIKHAR = new File("SHIKHAR");
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(SHIKHAR);
```

BTW, as per your current code will simply read string and not from file named `SHIKHAR`.

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner("SHIKHAR");
```